# Написать функцию, определяющую количество элементов, последняя цифра которых – 7

Tags: c

В файле t.txt находится массив. Написать функцию, определяющую количество элементов, последняя цифра которых – 7

```
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE *f;
    int err;
    err=fopen_s(&f,"t.txt", "r");
    if(err)
    {
        printf("can't open file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int v, n = 0;
    while (fscanf(f, "%d", &v) == 1) if (v % 10 == 7) ++n; // программа проверяет что это цифра , если остаток от деления 7 то к n + 1

    fclose(f);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: @ScarfaceBIT, если вы хотите похвастаться своим кодом, выкладывайте его в Твиттер или на Гитхаб. А тут форум вопросов и ответов. Потрудитесь задать какой-нибудь вопрос.

Comment: @ScarfaceBIT, поздравляю!

А что, собственно, Вы хотите?

--

Вы бы хоть написали, что компилятор выдает такие-то ошибки и Вы не понимаете, что они означают и не знаете где прочесть про это, а поиск в гугле про `fopen_s()` Вы еще не освоили...

--

Маленький совет -- учиться программировать на C/C++ лучше в \*nix, а не в винде.

Comment: В чем вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос: Программирование, 1 курс?

Ответ: Да, это Программирование, 1 курс!

))

Поставьте метку "телепатам". Чего хотел ТС?

Comment: @ScarfaceBIT, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, а как вы представляете себе действия @ScarfaceBIT, который может и захочет уточнить, *что он сделал и что не получается* (как Вы ему советуете) при **уже закрытом вопросе?**

Comment: @avp, можно исправить текст вопроса, переоткрою - не жалко. Можно создать новый вопрос.  
Если Вы готовы помочь автору - переоткройте сами, но боюсь, что если Вы попытаетесь скомпилировать приведенный в вопросе код, поймете что хотелось сделать этим кодом, исправите ошибки и еще и, упаси Господь, выложите исправленный код как ответ, то от этого станет хуже только ТС, который так и не поймет, что вопросы надо задавать правильно.

Comment: @avp, модераторы такие модераторы...

это уже третий вопрос, судя по профилю вопрошающего, думаю первые два были такими же, но вместо того чтобы попытаться помочь человеку кто-то просто удаляет их...

Comment: @AlexDenisov, если бы человек хотел помочь сам себе, то он бы нормально сформулировал вопрос, можно разобрать этот вопрос последовательно:  
**Шапка** - в ней не хватает только "19 лет, рост метр с кепкой, голубоглазый шатен" к уже имеющемуся там "Программирование 1 курс"  
**Тело вопроса** - просто кусок кода с одним единственным комментарием  

> программа проверяет что это цифра , если остаток от деления 7 то к n + 1  

ну да, простите. Тут же все ясно как божий день, просто осталось скопировать код к себе, запустить его, найти все баги, исправить и выложить обратно.

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, я вовсе не против закрытия **таких вопосов**. Но *формулировка* д.б. какой-то другой.

Согласитесь, что использованный шаблон в принципе не верен. В нем явное противоречие между просьбой *уточнить* и действием (вопрос становится недоступен для редактирования).

Заранее согласен, что это тема для обсуждения на Мете, а не здесь, но так уж получилось...

А закрыть его (только, боюсь, формулировка не будет очень корректная) я и сам могу.

Comment: Это новый стиль вопросов. Обычно дают сам вопрос, но не показывают код. Здесь есть код, вопрос нужно угадать.

Comment: @avp, можно исправлять закрытый вопрос, даже если отрицательная карма.

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, вам, конечно, покажется это дикостью, но человек может банально не уметь задавать вопросы, у вас-то такой проблемы не стоит, вы ведь все с рождения знаете и умеете.

Минимальная помощь в такой ситуации не стоит вам ничего, как и закрытие/удаление вопроса, но вы почему-то выбрали второй вариант.

Comment: Всем привет, я так понимаю, это продолжение удаленного вопроса: http://hashcode.ru/questions/290983 , но ТС забыл перенести сам вопрос:

> В файле t.txt находится массив. Написать функцию, определяющую количество элементов, последняя цифра которых – 7

ЗЫ. На первом курсе, и правда, далеко не все умеют формулировать вопросы.

Comment: Наконец-то пришел экстрасенс и все сразу встало на свои места.

Comment: @ReinRaus, не все. Не ясно: это код уже рабочий у него или надо найти ошибку.

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, вот оказывается как. Я и не знал (видимо мои вопросы не закрывали). Тогда извините.

@KoVadim, м.б. этот новый стиль вопросов навеян Jeopardy:

    Особенность официальной версии игры в том, что вопросы звучат в  утвердительной форме, а ответы игроков даются в вопросительной форме. Например, Вопрос: Она рассказывала сказки в книге «Тысяча и одна ночь». Ответ: Кто такая Шехерезада?

а нас проверяют по Тьюрингу.

Comment: Видимо нужно предложить варианты неверного кода и правильные вопросы.

Хотя этот код будет неверно отрабатывать, если среди чисел будут буквенные строки.

Comment: @Nofate ♦, вот именно, что не все ясно и формулировка задачи не есть вопрос. Что хотел ТС? Что с этим кодом? Хотя бы работает/не работает или что здесь не так он мог бы сказать, тем более после такой дискуссии. И с @ReinRaus я согласен: 'если бы человек хотел помочь сам себе, то он бы нормально сформулировал вопрос'. Хотя бы простейший, но это умеют не только на 1-м курсе, а еще в детском саду.

Comment: Я думаю вопрос звучит как то так:

> Написал программу которая считает количество элементов у которых последняя цифра - 7. Но мне надо написать функцию и я не знаю как. Потому что учусь на 1 курсе, и функции еще не проходили.

вот, я думаю как то так :)

Comment: @IVsevolod: И ответ на такое в большинстве случаев «Прочитайте любую книжку по C++». Предлагаю добавить его в шаблонные комментарии.

Comment: @VladD, тогда лучше шаблон "Прочитайте любую книжку по `<subject>`", а значение `<subject>` подставлять автоматически из тегов )

Comment: @Nofate: так было бы даже лучше ;-)

Comment: >Но мне надо написать функцию и я не знаю как. Потому что учусь на 1 курсе, и функции еще не проходили

@IVsevolod ага, ТС - прям несчастный студент, всей душой тянущийся к знаниям. Если он что-то не проходил, то вполне логично, что учебная программа требует от него, чтобы задача была выполнена теми средствами, которые он проходил. А по сути ТС просто нерадивый студент хочет, чтобы за него сделали его работу,  и возмущается, не увидев желающих это сделать

Comment: @DreamChild я написал шаблонное сообщение, которым они обычно отмазываются. Мало кто напишет правду.

Comment: @IVsevolod ах вы в этом смысле) Я думал, вы поверили в чистоту и безгрешность его помыслов))

Answer (score 2):

Напишу и я свой вариант на C#:

```
return
    File.ReadLines("t.txt")
        .SelectMany(s => s.Split())
        .Select(int.Parse)
        .Where(n => Math.Abs(n) % 10 == 7)
        .Count();
```

Перевести на другой язык будет, надеюсь, несложно.

Comment: @VladD, да, шарп с Linq впечатляет.

--

Правда, не очень понимаю, почему они сделали такой вот синтаксис 

    .SelectMany(s => s.Split()) и .Where(n => Math.Abs(n) % 10 == 7)

но

    .Select(int.Parse)

Казалось бы, что 

    .SelectMany(string.Split())  и .Where(Math.Abs() % 10 == 7)


вполне достаточно (по крайней мере у меня это вызывает меньше вопросов).

Как считаете, @VladD?

Comment: @avp: Аргументом функций типа `Select` является другая _функция_. `int.Parse` — это уже существующая статическая функция от одного аргумента, как раз то, что надо. Функция `string.Split` принимает 0 аргументов и работает с `this`, поэтому я её «превращаю» в статическую, оборачивая в _лямбду_: `s => s.Split()` — это просто краткая запись для определения и использования функции:

    static string[] f(string s) { return s.Split(); }

`string.Split()` было бы не функцией, а результатом применения (ну тут точно как в C).

Так что этот C# имеет определённый смысл.

Comment: @avp: удобно было бы, конечно, что-то наподобие `Math.Abs(_) % 10 == 7`, чтобы сразу указывать место для формального аргумента. Но я не знаю, как можно красиво распространить это на случай нескольких аргументов.

---
Интересно, что и на C, без LINQ, можно устраивать подобные же вещи. Что и демонстрирует ваш ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения.

(и за Math.Abs(), конечно :)).

Comment: @avp: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD

       Но я не знаю, как можно красиво распространить это на случай нескольких аргументов.

Это Вы про point-free? (описание функций без указания аргуменнтов, "точек применения")

Comment: @alexlz: Не, я немного о другом. В C# есть синтаксис для лямбд: `x => f(x) + g(x)`. Его можно было бы упростить до `f(_) + g(_)`, назначив `_` формальным аргументом, но как в таком случае записать `(x, y) => f(x) + g(y)`? (В C# нету автокаррирования.)

Answer (score 1):

А вдруг человеку правда интересно, как одними функциями можно это сделать?

Вот, чуток развлекся... Если файл не задан, то читает stdin.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
cnt777 (FILE *in, int sum, int d)
{
  return  (fscanf(in, "%d", &d) == 1) ? 
    cnt777(in, sum + ((d % 10) == 7), d) : sum;
}

int
foo777 (FILE *in, const char *name)
{
  return (in ? cnt777(in, 0, 0) : (perror(name), 0));
}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  return foo777(av[1] ? 
                fopen(av[1], "r") : 
                (puts("enter numbers:"), stdin), 
                av[1] ? av[1] : "");
}
```

Понятно, что с длинным файлом рухнет по stack overflow, да и по причине ограничения разрядности кода возврата правильно посчитает до 255 7-рок.

**UPD**.

В более эффективном (да и просто понятном) итеративном стиле тело `cnt777` можно записать так

```
  return ({ while (fscanf(in, "%d", &d) == 1) 
               sum += ((d % 10) == 7); sum; });
```

По крайней мере gcc понимает блоки внутри выражений.

**UPD2**

Ответ [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd) на шарпе указал на неприятную ошибочку. Остаток от деления отрицательного числа -- тоже отрицательное число. Для исправления напишем функцию

```
static inline int iabs (int n) { return n < 0 ? -n : n; }
```

и подправим

```
  return ({ while (fscanf(in, "%d", &d) == 1) 
               sum += ((iabs(d) % 10) == 7); sum;});
```

код в `cnt777()`.